# Why does the number of client connections affect Redis performance?

Tags: networking, redis, benchmarking

I have been reading the Redis documentation and I don't understand the following paragraph (from link http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks):

"Naively iterating on synchronous Redis commands does not benchmark Redis itself, but rather measure your network(or IPC) latency. To really test Redis, you need multiple connections and/or ..."

I did the following testing to see the speed difference between 1 connection and 500 connections. As we can see, it is much slower when there is only 1 connection. But I don't understand why and how does the number of connections affect the Redis speed performance. I am new to computer networking, any help would be appreciated！

```
$ redis-benchmark -c 500 -t ping
====== PING_INLINE ======
  10000 requests completed in 0.10 seconds
  500 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

$ redis-benchmark -c 1 -t ping
====== PING_INLINE ======
  10000 requests completed in 0.19 seconds
  1 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When latency > throughput, you need multiple requests in flight to bottleneck on throughput instead of just round-trip latency.

e.g. if the network round trip is 10ms, then a client that waits for the result of one request before sending another is mathematically limited to 100 requests / sec.  If your server can handle more than that, you can't test it with a single client.

---

The logic is the same as for regular data transfer over networks, e.g. TCP window sizes.  This wiki article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product) might help clarify the concept of needing to keep multiple packets / operations in flight.  For a redis request, the total latency includes the processing time + the network time.  If you bottleneck on that, you won't come close to keeping the server's CPU (or network) 100% busy.

Note that achieving [Instruction-Level Parallelism in a CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) is the same concept, too.  (e.g. to sum an array of floats, you should use at least 3 accumulators if FP add has 3 cycle latency and one per 1c throughput, i.e. fully-pipelined).